# Simplify passing same arguments two two different functions

Tags: javascript

I'm calling two functions to which I pass the identical arguments.

```
foo1('p1','p2','p3','p4','p5');

//...

foo2('p1','p2','p3','p4','p5');
```

Can I do something like the following, to declare the arguments once and then pass it to both functions?

```
var params = 'p1','p2','p3','p4','p5'; // what's the syntax here?

foo1(params);
foo2(params);
```

Comment: You could use [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) `var params = ['p1','p2','p3','p4','p5']`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can: Put them in an array and use [`...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (in modern environments) or [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) (in older environments):

In modern environments:

```
const params = ['p1','p2','p3','p4','p5'];
// −−−−−−−−−−−−^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^

foo1(...params);
// −−^^^
foo2(...params);
// −−^^^
```

In older environments:

```
var params = ['p1','p2','p3','p4','p5'];
// −−−−−−−−−−^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^

foo1.apply(null, params);
// −^^^^^^^^^^^^
foo2.apply(null, params);
// −^^^^^^^^^^^^
```